# Prevent collection browser's cache by Selenium

Tags: java, json, selenium, selenide

My selenium tests are working correctly in mozilla and ie, but i need to adapt them for Edge. Selenium enters all fields, then clicks on continue button, but nothing happens and "**Converting circular structure to JSON**" error is displayed on the edge console. I tried to do the same steps by myself and it works correctly even in edge browser. This error is not displayed when i run these tests in another browsers.
I realized the reason of my error is var **$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_** which collects my browser's cache. There is html code for buttons, datepickers and another elements of the web form inside this var. My datepicker is circular structure but now it doesn't matter, because browser doesn't have to collect cache. Firefox and IE don't collect. What can i do to prevent collecting cache by Edge? I don't have to do any changes in edge driver.

Comment: Welcome SO. Please share the code what you have tried and error trace.

Comment: I think the problem is in the method JSON.stringify(value).
Error trace:
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLInputElement'
    |     property 'inputmask' -> object with constructor 'Inputmask'
    --- property 'el' closes the circle